# Determine if bash script is background or foreground

Tags: bash, unix

I'm creating a script which I want to output to stdout only if the process is in the foreground. The desired behavior is that you should be able to background the script and have it still run without clogging up stdout, yet you should be able to foreground the script again to check on the script's progress.

The snippet I've seen repeatedly is the case statement below:

```
function example() {
  while true; do
    case $(ps -o stat= -p $$) in
      *+*) echo "Running in foreground" ;; # this works at first, but after `bg` and then `fg` no longer works (why?)
      *) echo "Running in background" ;; ## this works
    esac
    sleep 0.25
  done
}
```

This works originally - when I start the script it correctly prints 'running in foreground'. However, backgrounding the script and re-foregrounding will cause it to print 'running in background' even after brought back to foreground:

```
Running in foreground
Running in foreground
^Z[1]  + 82818 suspended  example
$ fg
[1]  + 82818 continued  example
Running in background
Running in background
```

Is there another way of determining if an app is in foreground or background?

Comment: Not an answer but an alternative: 
When I understand your requiements correctly, `screen` might be the tool for you. It will allow you to start a process on the foreground in a "virtual" terminal. You can switch to your main commandline (and the process doesn't clog up your stdout). When interested, you can `attach` to the running process and see the output again.

Comment: there's no difference between a foregroud process and a background the only is that the foreground is that parent is waiting for it